# My P-value Manually Calculated is Different from when I use the Prop-Test, in R Studio

Tags: r, p-value

Trying to calculate the p-value manually and then demonstrate it using the Prop test but I keep getting different P-values.

```
> p_hat <- mean(flint_data$Pb >= 15)
[1] 0.1238447

> Sd <- sd(flint_data$Pb >= 15)
[1] 0.3297092

> SE <- sqrt(.1*.9/dim(flint_data)[1])
[1] 0.01289801

> z <- (p_hat - .1)/SE
[1] 1.848714

> p_val <- 1 - pnorm(z)
**[1] 0.03224953**

> test <- prop.test(x = sum(flint_data$Pb >= 15), n = 541, p = .1, alt = "greater", conf.level = 0.95)

    1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  sum(flint_data$Pb >= 15) out of 541

X-squared = 3.1579, df = 1, **p-value = 0.03778**
alternative hypothesis: true p is greater than 0.1

95 percent confidence interval:
 0.101559 1.000000

sample estimates:
        p 
0.1238447
```

Comment: This question is likely more appropriate for the stackoverflow community. If you do that do not forget to include your data set `flint_data`.

Comment: @rmagno I think there's a statistical issue here, even though it's presented as a bunch of code.

Comment: @Glen_b: Fair enough. But still a reproducible example will help others helping the OP.

Comment: Various implementations of the test take slightly different paths: (1) exact binomial, (2) normal aprx with continuity correction, (3) normal aprx w/o continuity corr. // For 2-sided tests: (a) double the a one-sided P-value (esp. for normal aprx), (b) various schemes for 'fairly balancing' the side opposite the data.

Comment: I had thought the answer would be revealed by consulting the documentation (via `?prop.test`) but, as with much `R` documentation, it's practically useless to all but the most experienced, because it doesn't actually tell anyone what this procedure does.  It drops hints about its use of the continuity correction and a chi-squared statistic, but this scarcely can be construed as adequate documentation!  I therefore vote to leave this question open.

Answer (score 4):

If you use prop.test() with the option correct = FALSE (which implies no continuity correction), then you should notice that the observed value of the test statistic reported by prop.test() is the squared value of the observed value of the test statistic you computed 'by hand'.

In your 'by hand' computation, you are computing the observed value of a z test statistic. Under the null distribution, this test statistic is expected to have a standard normal sampling distribution.

In the prop.test() computation, the test statistic (i.e. squared value of a z-test statistic) is expected to have a chi squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom under the null by virtue of how it was constructed.  Indeed, squaring a standard normal distribution produces a chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).